# How can get data within range?

Tags: python, loops

```
obsFirstClassArray = [479, 1448.147, 541.692, 1184.73, 2668.818, 1159.531, 525.242, 715.489, 711.0, 422.358, 1681.012, 2418.123, 1798.0, 1756.264, 2015.973, 1318.292, 2106.042, 528.5, 415.244, 3796.11, 1047.01, 1516.165, 646.705, 1637.236, 2337.71, 1059.644, 3215.303, 2756.235, 3192.125, 3274.501, 1204.304, 1737.25, 907.489, 1824.506, 628.075, 453.591, 964.125, 710.029, 717.817, 1393.557, 1426.171, 416.072, 739.597, 419.729, 1477.92, 1046.108, 1152.492, 3415.375, 3154.497, 3641.262, 3722.41, 3611.676, 3762.858, 689.71, 3649.2, 2052.045, 1127.46, 957.21, 570.256, 673.569, 2595.0, 3622.948, 3672.778, 747.099, 2459.65, 517.867, 540.28, 514.078, 2737.375, 3221.398, 2872.977, 754.37, 1106.124, 997.063, 1224.915, 466.911, 2729.25, 3109.625, 2067.125, 1130.5, 1621.376, 1957.471, 3808.968, 2326.75, 1421.764, 7009.088, 5930.857, 9186.095, 13291.356, 23698.799, 8798.074, 21714.114, 15574.125, 11112.625, 14937.0, 4351.402, 11384.579, 10564.059, 7223.75, 27821.241, 6405.0, 5030.387, 11452.005, 4915.75, 20737.125, 16062.25, 29792.424, 7617.884, 33135.874, 15092.375, 22489.929, 22787.852, 10443.0, 20199.447, 29725.186]

def withinBoundary(p,bound):
if (bound[0] <= p < bound[1]):
    return p
else:
    return None


minBoundary = [403.341,33882.0162,131936.8323] 

maxBoundary = [33882.0162,131936.8323,980586.2055]

bound=zip(minBoundary,maxBoundary)

for i in obsFirstClassArray:
    for j in bound:
        if (withinBoundary(i,j)!=None):

            print i, " is between", j[0]," and ",j[1]
```

> I want to get individual set of data between the specified range e.g [403.341- 33882.0162] in a list? How can I achieve this? So, far I am getting output something like following

```
8777.9956  is between 403.341  and  33882.0162
5877.80875  is between 403.341  and  33882.0162
5673.10075  is between 403.341  and  33882.0162
76450.3483  is between 33882.0162  and  131936.8323
```

-In the above sample output these numbers

```
(8777.9956,5877.80875,5673.10075)  lies between 403.341  and  33882.0162 and (76450.3483) lies between 33882.0162  and  131936.8323.
```

How can i get output into individual list of numbers? My output should be something like

```
list403.341 _33882.0162 = [8777.9956,5877.80875,5673.10075]      
list33882.0162_131936.8323 = [76450.3483]
```

Can I store list403.341 _33882.0162 = [8777.9956,5877.80875,5673.10075] into  variable?
Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe, there is no number in your array, which fits between the second and third boundaries. 76450.3483 is not in obsFirstClassArray.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a list of lists, of which each contains the elements that fall withing the corresponding bound.

```
out = [[el for el in obsFirstClassArray if withinBoundary(el, z)]
       for z in zip(minBoundary, maxBoundary)]
```

which produces

```
[[479, 1448.147, 541.692, 1184.73, 2668.818, 1159.531, 525.242, 715.489, 711.0, 422.358, 1681.012, 2418.123, 1798.0, 1756.264, 2015.973, 1318.292, 2106.042, 528.5, 415.244, 3796.11, 1047.01, 1516.165, 646.705, 1637.236, 2337.71, 1059.644, 3215.303, 2756.235, 3192.125, 3274.501, 1204.304, 1737.25, 907.489, 1824.506, 628.075, 453.591, 964.125, 710.029, 717.817, 1393.557, 1426.171, 416.072, 739.597, 419.729, 1477.92, 1046.108, 1152.492, 3415.375, 3154.497, 3641.262, 3722.41, 3611.676, 3762.858, 689.71, 3649.2, 2052.045, 1127.46, 957.21, 570.256, 673.569, 2595.0, 3622.948, 3672.778, 747.099, 2459.65, 517.867, 540.28, 514.078, 2737.375, 3221.398, 2872.977, 754.37, 1106.124, 997.063, 1224.915, 466.911, 2729.25, 3109.625, 2067.125, 1130.5, 1621.376, 1957.471, 3808.968, 2326.75, 1421.764, 7009.088, 5930.857, 9186.095, 13291.356, 23698.799, 8798.074, 21714.114, 15574.125, 11112.625, 14937.0, 4351.402, 11384.579, 10564.059, 7223.75, 27821.241, 6405.0, 5030.387, 11452.005, 4915.75, 20737.125, 16062.25, 29792.424, 7617.884, 33135.874, 15092.375, 22489.929, 22787.852, 10443.0, 20199.447, 29725.186],
[],
[]]
```

as you can see it contains three lists, one per given bound.

Otherwise, in case I have misunderstood what you are looking for, this gives you a list of tuples, each of which contains the element being checked and the range (bound) it falls into.

The algorithm assumes the ranges (bounds) are adjacent and disjoint (as they are in the sample code you have provided), so it can stop and return only the first match

```
from itertools import islice, dropwhile
def withinBoundary(p,bound):
    return p >= bound[0] and p < bound[1]

minBoundary = [403.341,33882.0162,131936.8323]
maxBoundary = [33882.0162,131936.8323,980586.2055]

out = [(el, z) for el in obsFirstClassArray
               for z in islice(dropwhile(lambda z: not withinBoundary(el, z), zip(minBoundary, maxBoundary)),1)]

print(out)
```

produces

```
[(479, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 (1448.147, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 (541.692, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 (1184.73, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 (2668.818, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 (1159.531, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 (525.242, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 (715.489, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 (711.0, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 (422.358, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 (1681.012, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 (2418.123, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 (1798.0, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 (1756.264, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 (2015.973, (403.341, 33882.0162)),
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use python's [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html):

```
for mi, ma in zip(minBoundary, maxBoundary):
   print (filter(lambda x:(x > mi and x < ma),obsFirstClassArray))
```

You can also use list comprehension:

```
for mi, ma in zip(minBoundary, maxBoundary):
   print ([e for e in obsFirstClassArray if (e > mi and e < ma)])
```

For storing the result, it's advised not to tie the result to a variable instead use lists.

Comment: I like to know why this answer is down voted though it was the first of it's kind? the reason will help me to improve my future answers. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
def withinBoundary(p,b):
        if (b[0] <= p < b[1]):
            return p
        else:
            return None

minBoundary = [403.341,33882.0162,131936.8323] 

maxBoundary = [33882.0162,131936.8323,980586.2055]

bound=zip(minBoundary,maxBoundary)

for j in bound:
    list = []
    for i in obsFirstClassArray:
        if (withinBoundary(i,j)!=None):
            list.append(i)
    print "list%s - %s = "% (j[0], j[1]), list
```

Produces:

```
list403.341 - 33882.0162 =  [479, 1448.147, 541.692, 1184.73, 2668.818, 1159.531, 525.242, 715.489, 711.0, 422.358, 1681.012, 2418.123, 1798.0, 1756.264, 2015.973, 1318.292, 2106.042, 528.5, 415.244, 3796.11, 1047.01, 1516.165, 646.705, 1637.236, 2337.71, 1059.644, 3215.303, 2756.235, 3192.125, 3274.501, 1204.304, 1737.25, 907.489, 1824.506, 628.075, 453.591, 964.125, 710.029, 717.817, 1393.557, 1426.171, 416.072, 739.597, 419.729, 1477.92, 1046.108, 1152.492, 3415.375, 3154.497, 3641.262, 3722.41, 3611.676, 3762.858, 689.71, 3649.2, 2052.045, 1127.46, 957.21, 570.256, 673.569, 2595.0, 3622.948, 3672.778, 747.099, 2459.65, 517.867, 540.28, 514.078, 2737.375, 3221.398, 2872.977, 754.37, 1106.124, 997.063, 1224.915, 466.911, 2729.25, 3109.625, 2067.125, 1130.5, 1621.376, 1957.471, 3808.968, 2326.75, 1421.764, 7009.088, 5930.857, 9186.095, 13291.356, 23698.799, 8798.074, 21714.114, 15574.125, 11112.625, 14937.0, 4351.402, 11384.579, 10564.059, 7223.75, 27821.241, 6405.0, 5030.387, 11452.005, 4915.75, 20737.125, 16062.25, 29792.424, 7617.884, 33135.874, 15092.375, 22489.929, 22787.852, 10443.0, 20199.447, 29725.186]
list33882.0162 - 131936.8323 =  []
list131936.8323 - 980586.2055 =  []
~ mgregory$
```

Note that your data doesn't contain the values you say you expected in the output.   That is a nasty trick.

Comment: @User1234 - the customary way of expressing thanks is to upvote useful answers and accept the answer that solved your problem (by clicking the tick next to it).   If you routinely don't do that, you reduce some people's motivation to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
assgn = 'list'
for j in bound:
    k = []
    for i in obsFirstClassArray:
            if i and j is not None:
                     a = j[0]
                     b = j[1]
                     lname = assgn+str(a)+' '+'_'+str(b)
                     if (withinBoundary(i,j)!=None):
                             k.append(i)
    print lname,k
```

This is your output

```
list403.341 _33882.0162 [479, 1448.147, 541.692, 1184.73, 2668.818, 1159.531, 525.242, 715.489, 711.0, 422.358, 1681.012, 2418.123, 1798.0, 1756.264, 2015.973, 1318.292, 2106.042, 528.5, 415.244, 3796.11, 1047.01, 1516.165, 646.705, 1637.236, 2337.71, 1059.644, 3215.303, 2756.235, 3192.125, 3274.501, 1204.304, 1737.25, 907.489, 1824.506, 628.075, 453.591, 964.125, 710.029, 717.817, 1393.557, 1426.171, 416.072, 739.597, 419.729, 1477.92, 1046.108, 1152.492, 3415.375, 3154.497, 3641.262, 3722.41, 3611.676, 3762.858, 689.71, 3649.2, 2052.045, 1127.46, 957.21, 570.256, 673.569, 2595.0, 3622.948, 3672.778, 747.099, 2459.65, 517.867, 540.28, 514.078, 2737.375, 3221.398, 2872.977, 754.37, 1106.124, 997.063, 1224.915, 466.911, 2729.25, 3109.625, 2067.125, 1130.5, 1621.376, 1957.471, 3808.968, 2326.75, 1421.764, 7009.088, 5930.857, 9186.095, 13291.356, 23698.799, 8798.074, 21714.114, 15574.125, 11112.625, 14937.0, 4351.402, 11384.579, 10564.059, 7223.75, 27821.241, 6405.0, 5030.387, 11452.005, 4915.75, 20737.125, 16062.25, 29792.424, 7617.884, 33135.874, 15092.375, 22489.929, 22787.852, 10443.0, 20199.447, 29725.186]
list33882.0162 _131936.8323 []
list131936.8323 _980586.2055 []
```